# WPF Binding in nested Item in a ItemCollection not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a `ListBox` control in which I manually create items. In the `Tag` property, I want to put another control with a bound property.
This bound property is shown in a `TextBlock` when related item is selected.
This looks like the following:

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="ItemsList">
    <ListBox.Items>
        <TextBlock Text="1">
            <TextBlock.Tag>
                <TextBlock Text="Content1" />
            </TextBlock.Tag>
            </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
            <TextBlock.Tag>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" /> 
            </TextBlock.Tag>
        </TextBlock>
    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Tag.Text, ElementName=ItemsList}" />
```

The `Textblock` binding is working since it shows the first item when selected.
The binding in the second item does not work. I've got a path error message in the log. If I change the binding path and change it back at runtime it works.
Looks like the nested control has no access to the other controls at initialization.

Do I have a mistake or do you have any workarounds?

Thanks!

---

### Edit

I simplified my problem to this quiet senseless example code. What I want at all is a bit complicated but I will try to explain.:
I have a UserControl from which are multiple instances shown in a list. Every UserControl can have its own Buttons which are stored in a Collection of UIElements. This Elements are shown in a ContentPresenter when the item is selected.
+ The Binding with the tag works if it's not in a list

Comment: Hi, what path error message do you get? Can you edit your question to include it please? Also, how do you create your `ListBox`? Is it within a `UserControl`?

Comment: Can you share your ViewModel? Also why do you need to bind `Text` to parent user control `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}`, maybe you need to bind it to list item?

Comment: The element assigned to the Tag property is not part of a visual or logical tree, hence it has no ancestor. It seems totally odd to have a UI element in a Tag in the first place. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @MrFC, is there any concrete purpose in creating textBlock for Tag? you can bind Tag: `Tag="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"`